# SharePoint promoted links on multiple rows with scrolling

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, promoted-links

Is there a way for SharePoint to displayed promoted links in 2 rows and still maintain the scrolling feature? When I added this script to display multiple rows I lose the scrolling feature.

```
script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {



// Update this value to the number of links you want to show per row

var numberOfLinksPerRow = 7;



// local variables

var pre = "<tr><td><div class='ms-promlink-body' id='promlink_row_";

var post = "'></div></td></tr>";

var numberOfLinksInCurrentRow = numberOfLinksPerRow;

var currentRow = 1

// find the number of promoted links we're displaying

var numberOfPromotedLinks = $('.ms-promlink-body > .ms-tileview-tile-root').length;

  // if we have more links then we want in a row, let's continue

  if (numberOfPromotedLinks > numberOfLinksPerRow) {

    // we don't need the header anymore, no cycling through links

    $('.ms-promlink-root > .ms-promlink-header').empty();

    // let's iterate through all the links after the maximum displayed link

    for (i = numberOfLinksPerRow + 1; i <= numberOfPromotedLinks; i++) {

      // if we're reached the maximum number of links to show per row, add a new row

      // this happens the first time, with the values set initially

      if (numberOfLinksInCurrentRow == numberOfLinksPerRow) {

        // i just want the 2nd row to

        currentRow++; 

        // create a new row of links

        $('.ms-promlink-root > table > tbody:last').append(pre + currentRow + post);

        // reset the number of links for the current row

        numberOfLinksInCurrentRow = 0    }    
// move the Nth (numberOfLinksPerRow + 1) div to the current table row    
$('#promlink_row_' + currentRow).append($('.ms-promlink-body > .ms-tileview-tile-root:eq(' + (numberOfLinksPerRow) + ')'));    

// increment the number of links in the current row

    numberOfLinksInCurrentRow++;  }

}

});

</script>
```